# VC6 IDE and Serena Dimensions

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-6, serena

Anyone know, how to configure Serena Dimensions or VC++ IDE to get Dimensions integrated into IDE? i tried to check IDE options, but it does not seems to have such thing.

PS : I have both VC6 Ide and Serena Dimensions client installed in my computer.

Comment: What makes you think that Serena Dimensions supports the VC++ 6 IDE? Do they say that they do?

Comment: Few days back, when i used to open the VC++ IDE it used to show the serena dimensions logo before starting. so i believe they have some integration. further more i have used PVCS dimensions with VC++ integration sometimes back and it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the SCC provider for Serena Dimensions. It is contained in the Desktop client installation as a file called **sccpcms.dll** (in the prog directory). Also in the directory is a program called **scc_test.exe** which let's you test the SCC connection.

Support for VC++ 6.0 is the tricky part. You are not going to get support out of the box maybe these would help:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319318

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165948(VS.80).aspx